# Behaviour of Java RegExp '?' and '+'

Tags: java, regex

Why does this regex evaluation returns 'false' ?
Pattern.matches("[abc]?", "abc") // false.

As per definition '?' evaluates if the string matches 'zero or 'one' occurrence of a or b or c.
To my understanding, there is exactly 'one' occurrence of each of a , b, c so it should be true, but it is false. Why?

In case of next line of code- Pattern.matches("[abc]+", "abc")  / returns true ( evaluates one or more occurrence of a or b or c )
which is correct, as there is one occurrence of each of a, b, c.

As long as there is only one occurrence, '?' or '+' both should evaluate same. I am not able to understand how 'false' is evaluated in case of '?'
Can some one please explain it?

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[abc]?", "abc")); //false (a or b or c comes zero or one time);
            System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[abc]+", "abc")); //true  (a or b or c comes one or more time)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `[abc]?` matches zero or one character that can be either `a`, `b`, or `c`. Thus it does not match `abc`. Positive matches would be the empty string, `a`, `b`, or `c`.

On the other hand `[abc]+` matches one or more characters that can be either `a`, `b`, or `c`. Therefore, it can match the 3 character string `abc`. Also `aaa` or `bbba` would match.